# URL parameter error on BigCommerce home page

Tags: http, bigcommerce, url-parameters

I have a bigcommerce store. I tried to use a 3rd party tracking tool that adds some url parameters to the url for tracking. It works well on all pages, except of home page. For example
http://twigpencils.com/cloth-pencils?param=1 and same version without the param (just delete the param=1) bring me to the same page (with the url param on the relevant page).

However, when trying the same on the home page
http://twigpencils.com/?param=1 creates a 404 error vs regular home page without the param (?param=1) that works just fine.

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks
John

Comment: Hi--not sure that this is a programming question--seems more like an issue for BigCommerce support maybe?

Answer (score 0):

John, I want to help you with this but first, I see 3 issues that could be affecting the behavior you describe:

### First, a Broken Meta Tag

At around line 8 of your HTMLHead.html file, your meta tag for keywords is broken:

```
<meta name="keywords"twig pencil,apple pencil,apple pencils,dictionary pencil,graphite,chaparral,colored pencils " />
```

It's missing the `content=` attribute.  It should look like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="twig pencil,apple pencil,apple pencils,dictionary pencil,graphite,chaparral,colored pencils" />
```

---

### Second, A Major Syntax Error

This error may be breaking several functions on your page.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    Line: 34
```

At around line 34 in your HTMLHead.html Panel file, a couple lines above where you placed the Google Webmaster Verification meta tag, one of your javascript tags is incomplete:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async defer
</script>

     <meta name="google-site-verification" content="3TJvxTrq55AqFcwuo2KtEH1uUMBZPyeQ5LBnmVh8OKk" />
```

The problem is at the end of this line `<script type="text/javascript" async defer`, as its missing a closing **`>`**.   The code should at least look like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async defer>
</script>

     <meta name="google-site-verification" content="3TJvxTrq55AqFcwuo2KtEH1uUMBZPyeQ5LBnmVh8OKk" />
```

However, considering it has `async defer`, it leads me to believe that it was supposed to load an external script, and either someone deleted the `src`attribute and also accidentally deleted the `>`, or some improper BC commenting or something of that nature is breaking the tag.  I can help further if I saw the actual code as it is in the BC Design backend.

---

### Third, Non-WWW or WWW

I notice that when I navigate to `http://twigpencils.com/?param=1`, it takes me to `http://www.twigpencils.com/`, which would be fine, except that when I navigate to `http://twigpencils.com/cloth-pencils?param=1` it takes me to `http://twigpencils.com/cloth-pencils?param=1`.

This is a fairly major problem, but is fairly easy to solve.

Either you need to forward from WWW to non-WWW on your domain/hosting backend, and/or [do the same on your Google Webmaster Panel](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en), or do both.

Before we try to figure out the main problem you mentioned, you should resolve these 3 issues first as they could be affecting the behavior you describe, but are at the very least breaking many things on your site.

---

Let me know if this helps and if you have nay other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with a broken .htaccess file, causing PHP to not correctly parse the parameters. Unfortunatly bigcommerce does not allow you to edit the .htaccess file directly.

I'd recommend checking out shopify or another platform. I've been trying to get support from bigcommerce on this for weeks, to no avail. Their support team is not very helpful.